# Print a pattern sequence of numbers in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

I need to write a method called `printOnLines()` that takes two arguments an integer n and an integer inLine and prints the n integer, every `inLine` on a line.

```
for n = 10, inLine = 3:
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
10
```

My call is `(10,3)`. Here's my code:

```
public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {
        for(int i=1; i<=s; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<=n-1; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + ", ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that there are two mistakes:

1. I need to remove the last comma appearing in the output.
2. I need to place 3 of the numbers of each line until I reach the
   number 10.

Comment: You should be able to do this with one for loop and an if.  The for loops through all the numbers, printing them one by one, the if checks the modulus to see if it needs to output the line break.

Comment: I shouldn't use if statements because it can be solved using nested for loops. There's a trick

Comment: You shouldn't or you aren't allowed? Also assuming this is homework.  No need for the all caps, by the way.

Comment: Ok, why are you yelling at me?

Comment: The trick is you put your comma at the front with a ternary to check the length.  Technically, that's still an if statement, just doesn't use the word `if`

Comment: "I shouldn't use if statements because it can be solved using nested for loops." It _can_ be solved using nested for loops, but that isn't optimal (O(n) vs O(n^2)).  Now my question stands, you "shouldn't" or your assignment tells you to use nested for loops?

Comment: No, my assignment tells me to use nested for loops. I'm still a novice  in programming.

Comment: Ok, that's fine, just trying to get clarification.

Comment: First, is it just `if` you can't use?  Or any conditional?  Also, your inner loop is broken.  It always starts at 1.  It needs to start at the end of the previous loop, or at least add `j + i` when you print it.

Comment: I shouldn't use any conditionals yet, though it is obviously simple to solve using if/else statements. However, I am limited to the use of for loops.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to correctly format the commas without using any if statements. Are you sure you're not allowed to use any at all? Even if you have nested for loops?

Comment: @turbo It's possible.

Comment: There is no way to not get the ending comma on there without some sort of conditional statement.  And, technically, a `for` is a conditional, it just conditionally loops.  In order to help, we need to know what the rules of the game are.  We can keep telling you answers, and you can keep telling us "no", or you can just say "all I can do is use a `for` or `while` loop" and then we will know how our hands are tied.

Comment: For what it's worth, the ternary operator can be used to conditionally print the comma doing something like: `i>0?','+j:j`, which will test if i > 0, and if so return ',' concatenated with j or just j.  Also, j is still the wrong thing to print out.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I have to use only for loops and nested for loops. I am  constantly debugging and running my program. The outer loop is fine; however, the problem is that, within the inner loop, I have to include  a code that respects both commas and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static void printOnLines(int n, int s){
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
         builder.append(i);
         if(i % s == 0)builder.append("\n");
         else builder.append(", ");
     }
     System.out.println(builder.toString().substring(0,builder.toString().length() - 2));
}
```

Comment: How is he supposed to learn if you just write code for him to use?

Comment: Also, uses an `if`.  He will yell at you for using an `if`.

Comment: I only need an insight. Some explanation that could ring a bell and help me solve it.

Comment: The op needs to put in the question that he can't use an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to post a complete solution, since this is clearly homework.  But here is what I would do, if I weren't allowed to use `if` statements or ternary operators.

- Make the index of the outer loop start at 0 and increase by `s` on every iteration, instead of by 1  (So it goes 0, 3, 6, 9 in your example).
- Print the sum of the two loop indexes on each iteration.
- Print the last number on each line outside of the inner loop, without a comma.

**Edit**

OK, on @localhost's request, here is my solution.

```
public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += s) {
        int j;
        for (j = 1; j < s && i + j < n; j++) {
             System.out.print(i + j + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(i + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I start with 0, then the output starts with 0 not 1.

Comment: Did you read what I said about printing the sum of the two loop indexes?  Have the inner one start at 1.

Comment: for(int i=1; i<=s; s+=3) {
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++) {

Comment: That's what I understood.

Comment: No, don't increment `s`.  Increment `i`.

Comment: public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {
  s=0;
  for(int i=0; i<=s; i+=3) {
   for(int j=1; j<=n-1; j++) {
    System.out.print(i+j + ", ");
   }
                        System.out.print("10");
   System.out.println();
  }
 }

Comment: OK, but isn't `n=10` and `s=3` in this case?  It seems that way from your question.  So maybe you want to have `i < n` and `i += s` in the outer loop.  I think your inner loop is a little wrong too.  But you're getting much closer now.

Comment: I didn't understand the concept of adding the loop indexes. Please explain the reason for using this addition.

Comment: It's just one way to do it.  Make the outer loop index go 0, 3, 6, 9 and your inner loop index go 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1.  Then the numbers with commas are the sums of the two indexes.  But it's not the only way.

Comment: David, your last point in your explanation above cannot apply to all cases and thus it's not flexible. I have to write a code that applies to all sorts of method calls, other than just (10,3).

Comment: It IS flexible.  I'm just explaining how it will work when `n=10` and `s=3`, so as to answer your question about why you'd add the two indexes together.  If, we had, say, `n=7` and `s=4`, the outer loop index would go 0, 4 and the inner one would go 1, 2, 3, 1, 2.

Comment: What do mean by "let the inner loop go 1, 2, 3, 1, 2" ?

Comment: So, the first time through the outer loop, the inner loop index will take the value 1, then the value 2, then the value 3.  The second time through, it will take the value 1, then the value 2, then exit.  This is for the case when n = 7 and s = 4.

Comment: But why these numbers? I can't understand the procedure.

Comment: OK, let's go back to `n=10`, `s=3`.  On the first line, when `i=0`, you want to print `"1, 2, 3"`  You'll print the 3 and the newline after the inner loop.  But to get `1,` and `2,`, you need `j` to be 1 then 2.  On the second line, when `i=3`, you want to print `"4, 5, 6"`.  You'll print the 6 and the newline after the inner loop.  But to get `4,` and `5,`, you need `j` to be 1 then 2.  OK?

Comment: So the upper bound of the inner for loop is supposedly 2 right?

Comment: In general, it will be `s-1`, except for the last iteration of the outer loop.  You'll have to have an `&&` in there to deal with the last iteration differently.  But try to get it working without that extra condition first.

Comment: I am almost there, except for some bugging additional numbers like 11 and 3.

Comment: I'm writing the numbers after the inner loop but they are iterating in response to the outer loop. How is that fixed?

Comment: The numbers that have commas (like 1, 2, 4, 5) will be printed IN the inner loop.  The numbers that don't have commas (like 3, 6, 9) will be printed AFTER the inner loop.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Yes. There's still an error. The numbers (3,6,9) are printed after the inner loop and contained within the outer loop, right?

Comment: Hello again! I have managed to fix my code:
public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {
  for(int i=0; i<n-1; i+=s) {
   for(int j=1; j<=(s-1); j++) {
    System.out.print(i+j + ", ");
   }
   System.out.print(i+s);
   System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(n);
 }
However, it only applies to calls such as (10,3) and (13,6). Why doesn't it apply to (10,4) or (13,7)???

Comment: @DavidWallace I've written an answer based on my understanding of your suggestions. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: @localhost Umm, more or less.  You didn't follow my instructions exactly, but if it works, then that's fine.  BTW, I would put the initialisation conditions for each `for` loop on the inside, like `for (int j = 1; j <= n; j+=s) { for (int i = 0; i < (s-1) && (j+i)<n; i++) {` - people are used to seeing and understanding this kind of thing.  Also, it saves you having to reset `i` at the bottom of the inner loop.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's what I did initially but I couldn't get it to work properly without resetting `i` at the end. It would complete the loop, printing extra numbers at the end. I also couldn't refer to `j` in the outer loop (`System.out.println(i+j);`) when `j` was created and initialized in the inner `for` loop. I would actually appreciate it if you could post a complete solution using your ideas, because I don't see how to make it work in the way you have described.

Comment: @localhost You were right; it was necessary to declare the inner loop index before the loop, not inside the `for`.  Other than that, my solution is just as I described.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already had to submit your homework, so here's how I'd do it:

```
class printonlines {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    printOnLines(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
}

public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {     
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {  // do this loop n times
        if ( (i != 1) && (i-1)%s == 0 ) {  // if i is exactly divisible by s, but not the first time
            System.out.println(); // print a new line
        }
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i != n) {  // don't print the comma on the last one
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Oh, you don't want to use any `if` statements. All you really learn from doing "tricks" like what you are asked to do is a single trick, not how to write easily comprehensible (even by yourself when you have to debug later) code.

Anyway, here's my less comprehensible but more tricky code that doesn't use `if` as per the suggestions from the answer from @DavidWallace. I'm sure someone can do it neater but this is the best I could do in 15 minutes...

```
class printonlineswithnoifs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        printOnLines(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
    }

    // i 012012012
    // j 000333666
  // i+j 012345678

    public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        for (; j <= n; j+=s) {
            for (; i < (s-1) && (j+i)<n; i++) {

                 System.out.print((i+j) + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println(i+j);
            i=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code sample you wanted..

```
public static void printOnLines(int n, int s) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + ",\t");
        if (i % 3 == 0) System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Comment: `if` wasn't allowed as per the OP's comment to his question. He should really have stated this major constraint in the question though.